# How to draw double circle node in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

Consider the following code:

```
\begin{document}



\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5 cm, scale = 1, transform shape]


\node[initial,state] (A)                                    {$s_0$};
\node[state]         (B) [right of=A]                       {$s_2$};
\node[state]         (C) [above of=B]                       {$s_1$};
\node[state]         (D) [below of=B]                       {$s_3$};

\path[->] (A) edge [left]       node [align=center]  {$ c = c + 1 $} (C)
      (A) edge [above]      node [align=center]  {$ c = c + 5 $} (B)
      (A) edge [left]       node [align=center]  {$ c = c - 1 $} (D)
      (B) edge [right]      node [align=center]  {$ c = c - 1 $} (D)
      (C) edge [loop above] node [align=center]  {$ c = c + 1 $} (C)
      (D) edge [loop below] node [align=center]  {$ c = c - 2 $} (D);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{An example of SST}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get the following automaton : 
[image]

How can I draw S2 and S4 as final states (double circle)?

Comment: You should also add a preamble to your examples. It is annoying to have to add them manually for test. Beside this, did you try to add the option `double` to your node?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That could be done by means of the option `accepting` (see as reference **25 Automata Drawing Library** in the pgfmanual version April 25, 2012).

Code (I assumed `s_1` and `s_3` as final states):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5 cm, scale = 1, transform shape]


\node[initial,state] (A)                                    {$s_0$};
\node[state]         (B) [right of=A]                       {$s_2$};
\node[state,accepting]         (C) [above of=B]                       {$s_1$};
\node[state,accepting]         (D) [below of=B]                       {$s_3$};

\path[->] (A) edge [left]       node [align=center]  {$ c = c + 1 $} (C)
      (A) edge [above]      node [align=center]  {$ c = c + 5 $} (B)
      (A) edge [left]       node [align=center]  {$ c = c - 1 $} (D)
      (B) edge [right]      node [align=center]  {$ c = c - 1 $} (D)
      (C) edge [loop above] node [align=center]  {$ c = c + 1 $} (C)
      (D) edge [loop below] node [align=center]  {$ c = c - 2 $} (D);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{An example of SST}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also, putting option `double` at those nodes.

Comment: Yes, it works too, but I preferred to use `accepting` since the OP works with the `automata` library.